# Lists vs. Key-Scanning

Tags: java, redis, key-value

I am using Redis to store Java objects. For example, I have a class User(FirstName, LastName) and each user has multiple addresses Address(Street, City).

Users are stored in the database as Redis Hashes:

```
HMSET user:0 firstname qwert lastname zuiop
```

As addresses are each logically bound to a specific user, their key includes the user's key:

```
HMSET user:0:addresses:0 street Teststreet city Exampletown
```

However, I am not sure how to provide the following features:

- Accessing all users in the database
- Accessing all addresses belonging to a specific user

Basically, I see two options:

1. Using Sets:

   ```
   SADD user user:0
   SADD user user:1
   ...
   SMEMBERS user (to access list of users)
   ...
   SADD user:0:addresses user:0:addresses:0
   SADD user:0:addresses user:0:addresses:1
   SMEMBERS user:0:addresses (to access list)
   ```
2. Using KEYS

   ```
   KEYS user:* (to access list of users)
   KEYS user:0:addresses:* (to access list of addresses)
   ```

Are there any alternatives to those approaches?
Which way is more "Redis"?

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT:** Do not use `KEYS` in production - it can block your application's requests while Redis is traversing the keyspace.

The lists method is certainly one way to go about it, but I'd consider the amount of space the lists will eventually require. Alternatively, I'd look into using v2.8's new `SCAN` commands to iterate through key name patterns in a non-blocking manner.